# CNN: Calculating Output Shape

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I am implementing a deep neural network structure that was published an year ago for comparison with my own work. The published neural network uses CNN as one of the components. The CNN outline can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjxQR.png).

In summary, 1D convolution is performed by a 2x6 kernel with the 2x6 input matrix. The authors extracted 32 features from the aforementioned convolution. I have written to the authors but am yet to receive any response about how those 32 features are extracted.

I would be deeply thankful if anyone here could help me figure out how the 32 output features are produced.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps your can provide the original paper?

Comment: I guess that perhaps 32 is the number of the channel of the convolution layer? Perhaps you are not familar with how the convolution is performed. You may refer to the PyTorch document of [1D convolution](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv1d.html) and [2D convolution](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html). If you can provide the original paper, I will be able to check my conjecture.

Comment: @hellohawaii https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877050919302935 Thanks for your time.

Comment: @hellohawaii Here's the updated version of the paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167404820301334

Comment: It is the channel number of the convolution layer. In another word, it is "the number of convolution kernel". For every convolution kernel of size 2x6 applied on one 2x6 part of the whole input "vector sequence", you get a scalar, and using 32 convolution kernels, you can get 32 features. It is something like `torch.nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1, out_channels=32, kernel_size=1, stride=1 `. Perhaps you should review how convolution is conducted. Perhaps [the CS231n](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/2021/lecture_5.pdf) slides will help, you may start from page 65. Pay attention to page 78.

Comment: @hellohawaii Man you have no idea how much your help meant to me. I will go have a look at those slides that you mentioned. Deeply grateful.

Comment: You may also refer to [the CS231n Videos](https://youtu.be/bNb2fEVKeEo?list=PL3FW7Lu3i5JvHM8ljYj-zLfQRF3EO8sYv&t=934)

Comment: Will do. Thanks. And can you submit your previous comment as an answer so I could accept it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the channel number of the convolution layer. In another word, it is "the number of convolution kernel". For every convolution kernel of size 2x6 applied on one 2x6 part of the whole input "vector sequence", you get a scalar, and using 32 convolution kernels, you can get 32 features. It is something like `torch.nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1, out_channels=32, kernel_size=1, stride=1`

Perhaps you should review how convolution is conducted. Perhaps the [CS231n](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/2021/lecture_5.pdf) slides will help, you may start from page 65. Pay attention to page 78. You may refer to the PyTorch document of [1D convolution](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv1d.html) and [2D convolution](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html).